# Is there a WPF Control that can display my overview ? How can I use it?

Tags: wpf, user-interface, gridview

I am moving from a place with 2 rooms, to a place with 3 rooms.
I need an application that generates an overview regarding the stuff I need to move.
It needs to display for me, how many boxes need to be moved from one room to another.
Correction: (The boxes need to be items in general so I can do the same for say, plants)

[image: Moving stuff overview]

Comment: Features that it will dynamically adjust the window resolution, in order to fit it content is more important, than the need to edit it's data (The user doesn't need to edit the data). so I need something that is optimized for reading.

Comment: It may be be that I actually want to solve a more general scenario that the moving overview ;-)